# VB.NET textbox maxlength for positive/negative integers

Tags: vb.net, textbox, integer, validation, maxlength

The problem is simple: I have a form with textboxes, and in one of those textboxes, I want users to enter either a positive or negative **2-digit** number. I'm looking for an easy way to enforce this restriction, i.e. without having to parse the number and check whether its absolute value is below 100.

If I set the textbox maxlength to 2, they cannot enter numbers below -9. If the maxlength is 3, they can enter numbers above 99.

A masked textbox has no solution, I cannot make the "-" literal optional, or at least not that I know of.

What would be the simplest solution to this restriction: "An empty textbox will accept 2 input characters if no "-" is typed, otherwise it accepts 3"? Handling the change event to see if a "-" was typed and resetting maxlength seems a bit overkill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want a [`NumericUpDownControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s.aspx). Use that, and set its `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties. No validation code required at all, and easily solves your problem.

If you're stuck on using a `TextBox` then in short you're not going to get the desired functionality you want without actually checking the number. You could write a `UserControl` to do this and you could reuse it, but you still have to write some validation code.

Just validate the integer using ASP.NET/Javascript style validation. This example uses a label with a `ForeColor` of Red to display validation messages.

```
private void numberTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int number;

    bool isValid = int.TryParse(numberTextBox.Text, out number);

    if (!isValid) {
        validationLabel.Text = "Must be a two-digit number.";
        validationLabel.Visible = true;
        return;
    }

    if (number < -99 || number > 99) {
        validationLabel.Text = "Must be between -99 and 99";
        validationLabel.Visible = true;
        return;
    }

    if (isValid) {
        validationLabel.Visible = false;
        // Do something else with your number
        // if you need to.
    }
}
```

There's nothing wrong with having to write code to do validation. You probably won't achieve good results using existing designer properties otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for hinting towards the NumericUpDownControl.

Answer (score 0):

Check the KeyPress event of the Textbox and check if the character is Number or = "-"

This code to allow only Digit and negative sign, you can check if the number is bigger than 100

```
private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress (ByVal sender as object, ByVal e as KeyPressEventArgs)

  If (e.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OR e.KeyChar = '-') Then
         e.Handled = false
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, that would restrict users from putting in any other character than number or minus sign, but I'm catching the exception that Integer.parse() throws to see if anything else was typed. Thanks anyway :)